# Does $\Re(\operatorname{arccosh}(z))$ vanish with $\Im(z)=0, -1<\Re(z)<1$?,

Tags: complex-analysis

This may seem like a homework question to you but I'm a software engineer trying to get an argument for the improvement of arb, a complex ball open source computation package. I tried Wolfram and Sage but both give me complicated expressions for $\Re(\operatorname{arccosh}(z))$ that do not reveal the stated simple conjecture that it vanishes for $-1<z<1$.

At the moment the arb package returns an (epsilon) nonzero real part for $\operatorname{arccosh}(z)$, with $-1<z<1$ but if there were a proof this could be improved. Can you please help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After all, what is $\operatorname{arccosh}(z)$? A solution of the equation $\operatorname{cosh} x=z$, that is, $e^{x}+e^{-x}=2z$, $(e^x-z)^2=z^2-1$. If $-1<z<1$, denote $z=\cos u$, we rewrite our equation for $x$ as $(e^x-z)^2=-\sin^2 u$, $e^x=\cos u\pm i\sin u=e^{\pm iu}$, $x=\pm iu+2\pi ik$ has indeed zero real part.

Comment: I think this holds even with complex numbers.